# Phantom tap-and-drag gestures

Tags: lubuntu, touchpad, synaptics

Since upgrading to Lubuntu 16.10, about 75% of the time, single-clicking the touchpad button causes a "tap-and-drag" gesture, even though I'm not holding down the touchpad button.

I've tried modifying different `synclient` parameters, including `LockedDrags`, `LockedDragTimeout`, and `TapAndDragGesture`, to no avail.

I'm running Lubuntu 16.10 on an Apple MacBookPro1,1.

How can I prevent these phantom tap-and-drag gestures?